# URLClassLoader in eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, urlclassloader

I am implementing a plugin for content assist in xml. In the implementation I am loading the classes of a project as,

URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls,Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());

But when i make changes in the classes, and try for content assist, it still loading the previous class.

Does there any way to load new modified classes?

Comment: Why do you need to use a class loader? How are you using this?

Comment: because, the .class file is not the in the classPath of the plugin project. Its in user project.